# Eloquent, change default table name

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

In Eloquent, by default, the table name associated with a model will be the plural of the class name of the model.  This causes a couple of obvious problems, such as names like "Mouse," "Box," "Deer," etc.  I haven't been able to find anywhere that ways whether Eloquent can handle complex plurals.

A simple way to fix this would be to override the default table name.  I am aware that for each model, you can change the name of the associated table using `protected $table = "mice";`, but I am wondering if it can be done BY DEFAULT, to match the class name perfectly, so you don't have to add that line to every model.

*Aside*, if anyone happens to know whether Eloquent can handle complex plurals, I've been wondering.

Comment: Yes, it can handle pretty much everything, your examples for sure. `Str::plural()/Str::singular()` are methods you need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend Eloquent to create your own base model, and overwrite the `getTable()` method with your own logic.

Utilizing Laravel's `Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer` class, you should be able to get something you like. :)